# Call results that are produced using RStudio and RMarkdown

Tags: r

I am trying to call a result that is produced using RStudio. But when I call it in RMarkdown, it's ending up in error:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
data
```
````

Results in

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'data' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval ->   eval
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: you have to load your data inside your markdown document first.

Comment: This should be your syntax:

start with three back ticks {r setup, include=FALSE}
data <- read.table(file.choose())
data
end with three back ticks

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian That *was* the syntax, it was just formatted wrongly here.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Yes I realized that later.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is actually very clear:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'data' not found

— You did not define `data` anywhere in your code, you are just trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This should be your RMD code:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE} 
data <- read.table(file.choose()) 
data
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `library(knitr)` to your code, save it and then see if it works and keep your `include=TRUE`, otherwise output will not be their in your html document.

Comment: I am getting  Error in system(paste(shQuote(pandoc_path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) : 
  'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\pandoc\pandoc.exe --version'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... get_pandoc_version -> with_pandoc_safe_environment -> force -> system
Execution halted